# ubuntu install (tar 1.34) from source, issues with already installed (1.28b) package?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, package, tar

On ubuntu 18.04, I need to install a more recent version or tar (1.34); the version installed with the system via the package system is 1.29b.  I've already downloaded and built the package (./configure  && make), but I'm wondering about the proper way to install it.  Essentially, I want to replace the existing tar with the new one, but I suspect if I just do a "make install" the package manager won't be happy.  Do I need to deinstall using the package manager first?  Will doing so mess up dependency checks the package manager does for other packages?

Am I better off installing in a different location and explicitly using that version of tar for the specific purpose for which I need it?  This
[post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37625/how-to-install-tarball-packages-on-a-debian-based-distribution) says it should be installed in /opt.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use different directory. As example this can be `/usr/local` or `/opt` in both cases I will recommend you to use full path when execute the command. For example:

```
/opt/tar/bin/tar tvf tar_Archive.tar
```